# Rails iteration use join method on one attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sending out a mailer to clients when someone enters in a form data that matches against the database and they want all the data sent to them in the email.

So I chose to just iterate with each attribute with the following:

```
h1 The customer registration form has been submitted.
-@customer.attributes.each do |k, v|
  ul
    li
      strong #{k.underscore.split('_').join(' ').titleize}:
      ' #{v}
```

It will then show something like:

```
ID: 200
First Name:Bill
Last Name:Smith
Email:no@no.com
Business Segments:["Purchasing", "Residential", "Commercial"]
```

If I leave it as is, the mailer will display the email. However whenever I try #{v.join(', ')} it fails. So I tested it out an sure enough it's working because there are integers. **So how do I apply the join method solely on the attribute of business segments?**

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
-@customer.attributes.each do |k, v|
 ul
   li
     strong =k.underscore.split('_').join(' ').titleize + ': '
     - if k != business_segments
      =v
     - else
      =v.join(', ')
```

This does not trigger correctly.

Comment: what error do you get with your current solution?

Comment: you could try checking if the attribute is an array: `if v.is_a?(Array)` and there you can use your `v.join(', ')` and in the `else` `v`.

Comment: I'm actually getting wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) when doing is_a?

Answer (score 0):

is_a? sent me on a path to do a search on array so I did a condition of

```
if v.kind_of?(Array)
```

Works

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to use the following:

```
ul
  - @customer.attributes.each do |k, v|
    li
      strong = k.titleize + ': '
      = v.is_a?(Array) ? v.join(', ') : v
```

A couple of notes:

- I've pulled the `ul` outside the loop, as it's likely you're after a single list, with the attributes populating it
- [`titleize`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize) should be sufficient to transform the test without your other modifications
- The final line uses a ternary to establish whether the data is an array or otherwise, and presents the text as requested

Incidentally, Rubocop's style guide recommends using `is_a?` over `kind_of?`, and I've seen discussions that suggest preferring `is_a?` for inbuilt classes such as `Array`. Not that much in it though.

Hope that's useful, let me know if you've any questions / feedback :)

Comment: @Jake - did this help at all?